Error Encountered While Reading DigitalExperienceBundle Metadata
I need help while I try to read DigitalExperienceBundle metadata and get following error.
Error:
Web service callout failed: The WebService returned a SOAP Fault with the following details: 
   INVALID_TYPE: This type of metadata is not available for this organization.

Context:
This error arises specifically when i try to read or create metadata related Digital Experience site whose has LWR template. I encountered same error with DigitalExperience, DigitalExperienceBundle and DigitalExperienceConfig metadata.
I can get those metadata details from the workbench but not able to do it via metadata apex class.
Code:
public static void readDigitalExperienceBundle(String sessionId) {
    try {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService(sessionId);
        MetadataService.DigitalExperienceBundle bundle = (MetadataService.DigitalExperienceBundle) service.readMetadata(
            'DigitalExperienceBundle',
            new List<String>{ 'site/lwrSite1' } //lwrSite is the name of Site
        ).getRecords()[0];
        System.debug('label: ' + bundle.label);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }    
}

Can you please review and provide your feedback?
Thank you,
Brijesh

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
